# User "Hennes" is editing a lot of really old posts

Tags: support

The user [hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes) is editing a lot of old posts:

- [Kill Gnome in Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/486761/kill-gnome-in-debian)
- https://superuser.com/questions/485881/redmine-mongrel-server-uses-so-much-ram
- [ssh keys across servers](https://superuser.com/questions/486783/ssh-keys-across-servers)
- [How can I keep two folders synchronized when a new file is created in one of them on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/488395/how-can-i-keep-two-folders-synchronized-when-a-new-file-is-created-in-one-of-the)
- [How can I keep two folders synchronized when a new file is created in one of them on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/488395/how-can-i-keep-two-folders-synchronized-when-a-new-file-is-created-in-one-of-the)
- [Multiple apache-webservers on different machines all on same IP](https://superuser.com/questions/487680/multiple-apache-webservers-on-different-machines-all-on-same-ip)
- [impossible to format a RAW usb flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/642394/impossible-to-format-a-raw-usb-flash-drive)

There are more on his [revisions](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes?tab=activity&sort=revisions) page.

His account seems to be in good standing (25k rep), and all the posts he edits are being bumped.

Most of the edits are really insignificant typos.

Comment: Are you suggesting we do something or is this an FYI?  Are you asking if this is acceptable behavior?

Comment: Asking if it's acceptable. It seems like it isn't but I wanted to ask.

Comment: Read the edit summary.

Comment: @chipperyman573 - The reasons for the modifications to the posts you reference are explained.  I don't see a problem.  There is often attempts to cleanup invalid or unused tags every month.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He's doing it as part of the planned, and gradual removal of the server tag. He's been also fixing other issues with the post as per protocol. In short, things are going on [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). He's not fixing the typos, he's fixing the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Here at SU, we want answers to be read ACAP (As Cleanly As Possible)

Typos are plain sloppy and must be edited for quality control. I for one consider users who can't spell correctly or gloss over proper sentence structures to be completely ignorant and gladly begin my search for the answer elsewhere.

In fact, bumping questions or as I call it "Frankensteining" is looked upon as proper SU protocol per the question [I recently posed.](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7107/downvotes-on-necro-threads)

Again though, this is all about quality control and is of most importance.

Comment: While you are certainly right in general (fixing posts for grammar and spelling), the question is about a different thing. Indeed, bumping questions is good, as long as you provide a new, good answer, or make the questions substantially better. In this case however it is a side effect of cleaning up tags.