# How to post trivial answers when that is all that is required?

Tags: discussion, answers

Often a problem can be solved with a trivial answer, which can be stretched to make one complete sentence.  These kinds of answers are often done as a comment because they don't seem worthy of "answer" status or because maybe there could potentially be another facet to the answer and someone else can turn it into something more comprehensive.  Often these questions just end up in the "unanswered" collection.

What is the appropriate way to initially respond to such questions -- leave the trivial answer as a comment or leave anything that answers the question, regardless of triviality, as an answer?

Comment: Some possibly related discussion [here](http://meta.superuser.com/a/6127/144607) -- not to say that your answers need to contain "excess theory", but if you're unable to write an answer long enough for the minimum character limit, it's probably not worth posting. I can't think of many cases where an answer under the minimum character limit would be OK.

Comment: From the discussion in that link, it sounds like a one sentence answer is appropriate if that's all it takes to answer the question.

Comment: Sure, but the way I interpreted your question, it sounded like you wanted to answer with fewer characters than the minimum required?

Comment: If you are really sure that you have fully answered the question and that you have explained enough then you can add HTML comments to add non-displayed text.

Comment: Can you give an example? I've never hit the minimum character limit, mainly because instead of just giving the answer, I explain **why** it's the correct one